# Need help parsing JSON

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

The following code to parse JSON is not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
string jsonText =
    @"{
        ""John Doe"":{
            ""email"":""jdoe@gmail.com"",
            ""ph_no"":""4081231234"",
            ""address"":{                    
                ""house_no"":""10"",
                ""street"":""Macgregor Drive"",
                ""zip"":""12345""
            }
        },
        ""Jane Doe"":{
            ""email"":""jane@gmail.com"",
            ""ph_no"":""4081231111"",
            ""address"":{
                ""house_no"":""56"",
                ""street"":""Scott Street"",
                ""zip"":""12355""
            }
        }
    }"

public class Address {
    public string house_no { get; set; }
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string zip { get; set; }
}

public class Contact {
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string ph_no { get; set; }
    public Address address { get; set; }
}

public class ContactList
{
    public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        ContactList cl = serializer.Deserialize<ContactList>(jsonText);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What kind of problem are you having, is it not compiling, returning null, throwing a exception?

Comment: Any error messages/exceptions? Not certain at the moment, but don't think you the double quotes around the object names e.g. ""John Doe"" becomes John Doe.

Comment: What exactly don't work? What error message you get?

Comment: I believe the problem is with the double quotes around your object labels and string literals.

Comment: ContactsList.Contacts is null.

Comment: Have you tried escaping your quotes using \"?

Comment: The quotes are fine, it's a verbatim string literal

Comment: I had the input text in a file without the double quotes and it still wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON text isn't a list of `Contact`s, it's an object mapping a name to a contact, so a `List<Contact>` is inappropriate.

The following JSON text matches `List<Contact>`:

```
var contactListJson = @"{
    ""email"":""jdoe@gmail.com"",
    ""ph_no"":""4081231234"",
    ""address"":{                    
        ""house_no"":""10"",
        ""street"":""Macgregor Drive"",
        ""zip"":""12345""
},
{
    ""email"":""jane@gmail.com"",
    ""ph_no"":""4081231111"",
    ""address"":{
        ""house_no"":""56"",
        ""street"":""Scott Street"",
        ""zip"":""12355""
}";
```

so the following JSON would match `ContactList`:

```
var jsonText = string.Format(@"{ ""Contacts"" : ""{0}"" }", contactListJson);
```

EDIT: To deserialize the existing JSON format, try deserializing into `Dictionary<string, Contact>`.

Comment: I don't control the incoming JSON input. What do you think I should change in my classes?

Comment: Deserialize into `Dictionary<string, Contact>`

Answer (score 1):

Check out [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/).  It is well documented and highly extensible.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.json.org/

> "A value can be a string in double
>   quotes, or a number, or true or false
>   or null, or an object or an array.
>   These structures can be nested."

""John Doe"" is not a valid string.  If you want to keep the quotes then you would use this:

"\"John Doe\""

but I suspect you just want:

"John Doe"

Comment: -1, it's a C# verbatim string literal - `""` is converted to a single `"`